# Implementation of ElasticSearch scroll ID in Angular using ngx-datatable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, elasticsearch

I have a dynamic data which I am getting from backend and maintained by ElasticSearch.

Even though I have 1000 records it will send only 50 records along with scroll ID.

Now my point is that I am using ngx-datatable for server side paging; how can I use the scroll ID in Angular using ngx-datatable and data will be formatted as below?

```
 {
  "_scroll_id": "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAABopFmdNTC1zZTQ4VG4yZ0pGc2hVVV92ZFEAAAAAAAAaKhZnTUwtc2U0OFRuMmdKRnNoVVVfdmRRAAAAAAAAGisWZ01MLXNlNDhUbjJnSkZzaFVVX3ZkUQAAAAAAABosFmdNTC1zZTQ4VG4yZ0pGc2hVVV92ZFEAAAAAAAAaLRZnTUwtc2U0OFRuMmdKRnNoVVVfdmRR",
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "fullname": "Jack Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "address": "P.O. Box 902 3472 Ullamcorper Street\nLynchburg DC 29738",
          "published": "14/10/2017, 20:47:34"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "fullname": "Jamie Konan",
          "age": 33,
          "address": "Ap #443-336 Ullamcorper. Street\nVisalia VA 54886",
          "published": "14/10/2017, 20:47:58"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "fullname": "David James",
          "age": 36,
          "address": "737-2580 At Street\nIndependence Texas 87535",
          "published": "14/10/2017, 20:48:39"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#server-scrolling  this will help you

Comment: yeah but with id it is not there they have given with page number @pal

Comment: what's the logic of this id??

Comment: @pal if  i have 1000 records in database initally using elastisearch i will get only 100  but when user want to get next 100 set of records he needs to send this scroll id as body in post every time for getting 100 records using ngx-datatable it have functionality for page number not for id